# Object does not seem to be retained when instance variable assigned to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, instance-variables

I am having some sort of retention issue when I assign an object to an instance variable. It was my understanding that all local instance variables were `strong` so the assignment alone would be enough to make sure the object would not be destroyed as long as it was referenced by the instance variable, but this is not the case.

In the code below, I assign my instance `MKRoute` variable `myRoute` to the route from the calculate directions call. At that point `myRoute` exists and is valid, has steps and polyline etc. But later in my code, I attempt to access `myRoute` and I am getting a BAD ACCESS.

It appears to still have a memory pointer value, but the rest of the object is gone at least in the debugger. There is no polyline or steps etc. or at least not what it should be. There are no other assignments or modifications or `myRoute` in my code. What do I need to do to make sure that this object is not destroyed?

```
@implementation SomeClass

MKRoute *myRoute = nil; 

.
.
.

-(void) showRoute:(MKMapItem *)origin destination:(MKMapItem*)destination
{
    MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
    request.source = origin;
    request.destination = destination;
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = NO;
    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR %@",error);
            // Handle Error
        } else {
            [self drawRoute:response];
        }
    }];
}

-(void)drawRoute:(MKDirectionsResponse *)response
{
    for (MKRoute *route in response.routes)
    {
        myRoute = route;  // set the global route

        [mapView addOverlay:route.polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];
    }
}

.
.
.
@end
```

I am happy to concede its a global variable vs an instance variable, but I still don't understand why its losing its retention, if I try STATIC or __strong on the variable declaration it still winds up assigned in the drawroute and gone later.

Comment: FYI - `myRoute` is not an instance variable if it is declared in the middle of nowhere like that.

Comment: Your edit confirms that `myRoute` is not an ivar. It's a file global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Globals are not a typical or recommended way to store variables, and you didn't provide any information about the code that *accesses* this variable and the stack you get when you crash (which are critical in accurately diagnosing).

That said, your problem is likely that you are modifying this variable on one queue while accessing it on another. `calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:` executes its completion handler on the main thread. Is your crash happening when accessing it from some other thread? Updating pointer values is not promised to be atomic, and it is possible for you to receive a garbage pointer if you're reading and updating at the same time.

Comment: I am attempting to access it in 

-(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder  Which simply throws a bad access upon any attempt to access it.

Comment: That's doesn't help much. `MKDirectionsResponse` doesn't conform to `NSCoding`, so how are you even storing it? And that method is for storing specific objects, not globals (global state is stored via 
`application:willEncodeRestorableStateWithCoder:`). And what thread are you on at that point? A stack dump of the crashing thread is critical to understanding the issue, along with any errors printed to the console. It often will tell you what went wrong. Don't guess.

Comment: am working on custom ecoding it, but that's not the issue at this point, as it never even gets that far.  Any attempt to access myRoute just throws a bad access... no stack trace is given..

The whole entire method is nothing more than NSLog(@"route name %@",myRoute.name);   which it simply throws a BAD ACCESS in the variable itself in debugging it doesn't show any of the elements only that myRoute is  an NSObject nothing else.  It does have a pointer value, but appears to be nothing relevant/proper at that location, like the element pointed to was released.   Thread is thread 1.

Comment: Okay the stack trace is inconsistent, sometimes its giving me things like [__NSCFNumber name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1742356c0 other times it is something else, so it appears to me to clearly be that the memory pointed to by myroute is being released/reassigned (either that or just never properly assigned outside the method assining it to begin with) I don't understand why I even turned it explicitly into an ivar by defining it in @interface block but still get the same problem, in the handler its properly set in the later call its referencing something completely different.

Comment: The read attempt is happening far after the assignment so I don't think its a racing condition issue.

Comment: Code was Pre ARC, resolved by making variable a property... seems overkill, but it resolved the issue... absolutely insane.